# Configurable options block is missing

Tags: configurable-product

I've been editing within catalog/view/options/type/configurable.phtml and this other guy working on the template has been editing all over the place. Suddenly, the whole configurable options block (that renders configurable.phtml) went missing from the page. The following blocks are still in view.phtml:

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
```

and

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
```

What else might be missing that would cause the disappearance of the configurable options block? There are no errors in the server or Magento logs that are applicable. Nor any JavaScript errors.

Comment: Have you tested your exact same database on a fresh install of Magento? If the same thing happens it's pointing towards an issue with a setting somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was any changes made to /app/design/frontend/default/[default]/layout/catalog.xml?

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
 .....
            <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
            </block>
            <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
            </block>
            <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
            <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
```

Comment: Nope! Replaced it with a fresh file from the latest version Magento and no changes!

Comment: Did you check to make sure the `if` statement return true

Comment: Nope. Just took the code within the if statements above and dragged them outside of the if block and no change. I'm cntrl+shift+refreshing to make sure the page isn't cacheing and I know its not cacheing in the Magento system either.

Comment: And if you view page source of the code on the product detail page, it shows the code I have in configurable.phtml as commented out!

Comment: Try find out which .phtml file contain the comment

Comment: I know! It doesn't say! I've looked at all the associated files via template hints except core... ill do that now.

Comment: All default app/design/frontend/base/default files recovered... template used is renamed so it runs off default files. STILL NO CONFIG OPTIONS BOX! I'm going to try fresh core files too... As for the product itself, it is configurable, has the associated products, in "in stock" "available" and has 1000 quantity for each simple. Any other issues with product it could be?

Comment: @CaitlinHavener I have the same issue. Were you able to track it down?